# Problems getting a simple jquery 'hover' to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a container `<div>` into which I dynamically insert third-party content over which I have NO control, in other words, I get what I'm given.

If the inserted element on the third-party website had a hover state I have already stored that hover color as a hex color; I can't store it as a style, as this color variable is updated dynamically.

What I want to be able to do is apply that hover color variable to the element that's landed inside my container.

I can make it work if I code the style in advance, but, as I said, I don't know it in advance so I can't do so. This simple code does work, giving the link an orange hover state. (See my [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vVjg4/1/).):

```
<style>
    .hovering, #container a:hover {color: orange;}
</style>
<script>
    $('#container').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('hovering');
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hovering');
    });
</script>

<div id="container">
    <a href="something">
        some link
    </a>    
</div>
```

However, I have to use the stored hover color variable `hoverClass` and apply it, but I can't get it to work. I tried this but it's not working. (See [the fiddle I'm trying to make work](http://jsfiddle.net/cKpLk/1/).):

```
<script>
    var hoverClass = '.hovering, #container a:hover {color: orange;}';
    $('#container').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass(hoverClass);
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass(hoverClass);
    });
</script>
<div id="container">
    <a href="something">
        some link
    </a>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.hovering, #container a:hover {color: orange;}` is not a class, its a CSS rule.

If you need the colour to be a variable, I recommend changing to the following:

```
<script>
    var hoverColour = "orange";
    $('#container a').hover(function() {
        $(this).css("color", hoverColour);
    }, function() {
        $(this).css("color", "auto");
    });
</script>
<div id="container">
    <a href="something">
        some link
    </a>    
</div>
```

---

Alternatively, a simplier solution would be to add the style using jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    var hoverColor = "orange";
    $("head").append("<style type='text/css'>#container a:hover { color: " + hoverColor + "; }</style>");
});
```

[**-- WORKING FIDDLE --**](http://jsfiddle.net/dBELH/)

Comment: Why would you append the style? Why wouldn't you just add it to the html?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to pass addClass css values.

addClass just adds the class name to element. You need to define what the css rule does a in style sheet.

Like this. http://jsfiddle.net/cKpLk/27/

Example:

```
<script>
        var hoverClass = 'hovering';

        $('#container a').hover(function() {
            $(this).addClass(hoverClass);
        }, function() {
            $(this).removeClass(hoverClass);
        });
</script>
<style>
        .hovering, #container a:hover {color: orange;}
</style>
<div id="container">
    <a href="something">
        some link
    </a>    
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this Charlie, but I can't predefine the 'color' in a CSS class as I don't know it in advance - it has to come from the variable that holds it - I then need to apply that color variable to the element concerned

Comment: Ahh, fair enough. If you knew what the color was going to be server side before the page was generated, you could of output it with PHP. But I guess the other solutions are better,

Answer (score 0):

```
    var hovercolor = 'red';
$(function() {
    $("#container a").hover(function() {
        $("#container a").css('color', hovercolor);
    }, function() {
        $("#container a").css('color','');
    });
});​
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work - I put in a a jsfiddle to try - http://jsfiddle.net/ArZyk/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vVjg4/2/     make sure you choose jQuery framework in left menu

Comment: Well spotted! I've added it here to help anyone else too - http://jsfiddle.net/vVjg4/3/

Comment: -1 @DiaMonD This code won't work as expected. When hovering over any anchor element nested inside a `#container` element, **all** anchors will change to red, not just the one hovering over. http://jsfiddle.net/vVjg4/4/

Comment: It will only work for ones in #container... I showed on his example where he has only one link and as I understood it's not the problem finding the an anchor, bot changing the color.